# Updating textbox value, more then once in webform asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, concatenation, string-concatenation

I am trying to update a textbox with a string. The string will be concatenated then will update the textbox with a click event. I can do this in a windows app, but when I try to do this in a asp.net app, I can't get the result that I want.

```
public partial class WebForm3 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string string_punch;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MultiView1.SetActiveView(View1);            
        txt_punch.MaxLength = 4;
        txt_punch.Attributes.Add("OnChange", string_punch);            
    }

    protected void btn_punch_7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        const string string_punch_Number_7 = "7";
        string_punch = string_punch + string_punch_Number_7;
        txt_punch.Attributes.Add("Value", string_punch);
    }

    protected void btn_punch_8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        const string string_punch_Number_8 = "8";
        string_punch = string_punch + string_punch_Number_8;
        txt_punch.Attributes.Add("Value", string_punch);
    }
```

I want to be able to click btn_punch_7, then click btn_punch_8, and concatenate the string, and update the textbox with both numbers. Every time I click a button, the string gets set to null. Thanks for advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`string_punch` is lost between every `PostBack` and that is why it always equals `null`, because ASP.NET is stateless meaning it does not keep it state from post back to post back. Also use `Text` property of `TextBox` to assign/retrieve value of textbox.

Change your events accordingly to code below:

```
protected void btn_punch_7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   const string string_punch_Number_7 = "7";
   var text = txt_punch.Text;
   text += string_punch_Number_7

   txt_punch.Text = text;
}
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks I was about to pull my hair out. I figured that was what was causing it, but I couldn't figure out how to get around it. I have a feeling that this is not the last time that asp.net is going to confuse me.

Answer (score 0):

Store `string_punch` in `Session`, so add this code to the load:

```
if (Session["string_punch"] == null)
{
    // this will only happen ONE TIME per session
    Session["string_punch"] = "your INITIAL static value";
}
string_punch = Session["string_punch"];
```

now the value of `string_punch` will be preserved between post backs. What's happening in your code is when the page is rebuilt during a post back, `public string string_punch;` is redefining this variable.

Now after every click just add this line:

```
Session["string_punch"] = string_punch;
```

Comment: I am curious about this as well. I am going to try this one out too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the attribute value to the element each time. Rather than doing that just do.

```
txt_punch.Text = string_punch;
```